# Apache shutdown unexpectedly on Windows 10

Tags: apache, xampp, windows-10

I know this question is asked so many times before but for the whole last day I have tried nearly every suggested solution I could find.

Below is my xampp control panel:

> [image]

At first MySQL did not start at all, and I sucessfully fixed that. But to apache, no matter what I tried, the problem still persists.

> I don't have IIS. I just removed Skype from my laptop.

> I installed xampp in D:\xampp.

> I have MS Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable.

Below is the list of things I have tried:

1. Configure ports: I haved changed the port number from 80 to 8080 in httpd.conf, 443 to 4433 in httpd-ssl.conf. These ports are free as shown below:

> [image]

All three lines related to port 80 and 443 in httpd.conf and http-ssl.conf have been change to 8080 and 4433 respectively.

2. Uninstall Antivirus (Kaspersky), MySQL, previous xampp, Skype and reinstall new xampp
3. Start apache service from services.msc
4. Disable firewall in Settings
5. Start apache_start.bat in cmd

> [image]

6. Run setup_xampp.bat

> [image]

I think the screen above shows a lead to whatever error I'm having but I don't really know what to do looking at this error log.

7. Run xampp_start.exe

> [image]

No error was shown!

8. Run http.exe

> [image]

No error was shown!

Below is my apache error.log:

> [image: apache error log]

I searched about 'server certificate does not include an ID ...' but they said that this is just a warning and no helpful solution is given.

I'm using Win10 which has not been activated, but I don't think this has anything to do with the current issue.

Could you suggest for me a way to solve this? Forgive me if this is asked many times before.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this. By installing and running https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe
from
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0

After PC restart apache ran smoothly
[image]